Navigation Framework Back Button Always Navigates Back To Start Destination
let me explain the issue in detail. I've been working on to solve this problem for like a week.
Github project link
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/materialToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_navigation"
                app:menu="@menu/material_toolbar_menu">

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.PrimarySurface"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>



This is my bottom-nav-menu that includes 4 sub nav-graphs (Firsts,Seconds,Thirds and Fourths)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_firsts_graph"
        android:title="First"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_first"
        app:showAsAction="always">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_seconds_graph"
        android:title="Second"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_second"
        app:showAsAction="always">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_thirds_graph"
        android:title="Third"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_third"
        app:showAsAction="always">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_fourths_graph"
        android:title="Fourth"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_fourth"
        app:showAsAction="always">

    </item>

</menu>

And finally main_activity:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.firstFragment,
            R.id.secondFragment,
            R.id.thirdFragment,
            R.id.fourthFragment
        ),binding.drawerLayout)

        // Toolbar
        binding.materialToolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
        binding.materialToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            menuItem.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView))
        }

        // Nav Drawer
        binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            menuItem.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView))
            binding.drawerLayout.close()
            true
        }
        // Bottom Nav View
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}

So far, there are no issues. The bottom navigation view is working smoothly and adapting well to the multiple backstack scenario. For example,
First Fragment (Start Destination) -> First 1 (Navigate) -> First 2 (Navigate) -> First 3 (Navigate) -> Second Fragment (Clicked Bottom Nav View) -> Second 2 (Navigate) -> Third Fragment (Clicked Bottom Nav View) -> Back Button -> First Fragment (Start Destination)
At this point, if i clicked back button, backstack completely ignored and goes back to First Fragment, although we expect to navigate back to Second 2.
To solve this problem, I tried using android:menuCategory="secondary" but it leads to new problems.
If we use android:menuCategory="secondary" bottom nav view buttons ignore backstack.
